# In Scala how do you reference index in List of Serializable?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, actually learning it. I'm trying to combine multiple Lists and print a table by passing the list into a function. However when I try referencing values by index I get the error

> Serializable does not take parameters

> println("%3s%3s%3s\n".formatted(elm(0),elm(1),elm(2)))
> val list1 = List("1","2","3")
> val list2 = List("1","1","5")

```
var newLst = List[Serializable]()

newLst :+= list1
newLst :+= list2

def display_table(a:List[Serializable]){

  println("%3s%3s%3s\n".formatted("A","B","C"))
  for (elm <- a){
      println("%3s%3s%3s\n".formatted(elm(0),elm(1),elm(2)))
  }
}

display_table(newLst)
```

How what is the proper way of combining Lists of Lists and being able to iterate through them and reference them by index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer is that you don't have a `List` of `List`s, you have a `List` of `Serializable`s and you can't index into a `Serializable`.

But you don't need to index into the `List` to get the leading elements, just use `match`:

```
val list1 = List("1", "2", "3")
val list2 = List("1", "1", "5")
val newLst = List(list1, list2)

def display_table(a: List[List[String]]) = {
  println("  A  B  C")
  for (elm <- a) {
    elm match {
      case a :: b :: c :: _ =>
        println(f"$a%3s$b%3s$c%3s")
      case _ =>
        println("Not enough elements")
    }
  }
}

display_table(newLst)
```

Or use `foreach` directly rather than `for`:

```
def display_table(a: List[List[String]]) = {
  println("  A  B  C")
  a.foreach{
    case a :: b :: c :: _ =>
      println(f"$a%3s$b%3s$c%3s")
    case _ =>
      println("Not enough elements")
  }
}
```